# Migration script for sequelize nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

We have a orders table in mysql, and now we are adding order_number field in table.
Now how to write migration script in sequelize to assign order_number from 1 to 500 to existing orders and when orderr_number reaches 500 then it should again start from 1.

I have tried writing raw queries in sequelize migration script , but no luck so far.

Comment: ___when orderr_number reaches 500 then it should again start from 1___ Huh? Would be interested to hear the logic for that one, if logic is the right word

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes Exactly :))